# Exercise 2.2b from A New Introduction to Modal Logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am kind of stuck on page 48 on exercise 2.2b in Hughes and Cresswell; In case you don't have the book at hand here's the question:

Let K** be K but with N and K replaced by

> LT: **L( p→ p)**,
>
> R*: **⊢ a → b ⇒ ⊢ La → Lb**

and

> K2*: **(Lp&Lq) → L(p&q)**.

Show that K and K** have the same theorems.

What I thought is that in 2.2a we have showed that LT+R* ⊢ N, so it's enough to show that LT+R*+N+K2* ⊢ K.

Now I thought of old trick of math to look from the end back to the start of the proof, i.e:

We need to prove:

> **L(p → q) → (Lp → Lq)**

But I don't see how to use the other rules and axioms, any hints?

Comment: It's not enough to show that the axioms of K** imply the axioms of K (that would only prove that the theorems of K are a subset of the theorems of K**), you also have to show the reverse. (Also: formatting your question better might help.)

Comment: Yes, I know but in part a of this question I have shown that LT+R |- N and that N|- LT, and since R is DR1 in K system I've showed that K and K* have the same theorems in in 2.2a. Now for 2.2b I am left with only showing that K** implies K since it's evident that K implies K**.

Comment: @EliranH do we have latex capabilities in the stackexchange?

Comment: No, unfortunately not (because it's in beta I guess).

Comment: @EliranH then how to edit my post for better formatting?

Comment: What about 6.10? We have to prove that the system K + [L(Lp-->q) v L(Lq-->p)] is complete with respect to the class of frames in which if W1RW2 and W1RW3 then either W2RW3 or W3RW2.

Comment: @ValentinoBianchi do you refer to Exercise 6.10? I didn't get that far in reading the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted one of the authors of the textbook, Max Cresswell and he kindly suggested me a solution to the problem.

All I need to prove is that K follows from K**.

So here's a proof:

1. ((p->q)&p)->q PC axiom.
2. L((p->q)&p)->Lq 1,R*.
3. (L(p->q)&Lp)->L((p->q)&p) K2*.
4. L(p->q)->(Lp->L((p->q)&p)) 3,PC.
5. L(p->q)->(Lp->Lq) 2,4, PC.

Where PC is axiom of propositional logic, and in 5 I used a sort of hypothetical syllogism.